# how to use hook deleted_user into custom function to delete user from custom table

Tags: plugin-development, customization

I have a second user table in my WordPress database for a separate application that I am integrating. I need to be able to delete a user from this second table when the user is deleted in the WordPress admin. I understand that the the add_action hook I need to use is deleted_user, but what would I use as an identifier in the WHERE clause of $wpdb->delete query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`delete_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_user/) action you can pass in the `user_id` and use that as a basis to delete the user from your addtiional table. This is, of course, assuming you *use* the `user_id` to make a relation between the two table. If not you can use [`get_userdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) passing in the `user_id` to get  more user information. It would look something like this:

```
function custom_remove_user( $user_id ) {
    // $user_meta = get_userdata( $user_id );    // IF you need additional user info before removal
    ...
}
add_action( 'delete_user', 'custom_remove_user', 10 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! It worked like a charm!

Comment: @HeatherFeuerhelm Great! If this was helpful be sure to upvote and click the checkmark so future readers know that this question was answered!